# keeping the whole gdb output log in file

Tags: linux, debugging, logging, gdb

Is there some way to keep the gdb log in a file.
I found:

```
    $gdb run.o
    (gdb) set logging file mylog.txt
    (gdb) set logging on
    (gdb)r
```

But it just keeps the logs of commands.
is there any option to have all the logs in a file ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and no.

GDB *cannot* do it because output from the program being debugged is not visible to it.

The poor-man's way to do it is using tee:

```
gdb <blah> | tee logfile
```

That will work, but you'll find that the interactive features of GDB are missing (autocomplete, paging, etc.).

My preferred method is to use the logging feature in my terminal. I use "Terminator" with its "logger" plugin enabled, but I'm sure there are other options.

Comment: The canonical way to record everything, without loosing interactive features, is `script(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any option to have all the logs in a file

From `man script`:

```
 script makes a typescript of everything printed on your terminal.
 It is useful for students who need a hardcopy record of an interactive
 session as proof of an assignment, as the typescript file can be
 printed out later with lpr(1).
```